# App Script debug success but execution failed.Why?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-apps-script-editor

I need to import csv files into specified google sheets from App scripts. I developed a code which works perfectly, but it does not show any output. What I did was I created an array to insert a list of csv files and another array to insert the sheet names in the active spreadsheet. then I created an if loop where the csv file containing array will push data if the index of that array equals to the index of array containing the sheets. I put this in an overall for loop to iterate. Below is my code.

```
function importCSVFromGoogleDrive() {

 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();// get the active spreadsheet


["Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3"].forEach(function (s) {
 var sheetArray = ss.getSheetByName(s);                   // getSheetByName


var numSheets = sheetArray.length; // save sheets in Array 


for (j = 0; j < numSheets; j++) { //loop to iterate

 var fileArray = DriveApp.getFilesByName["Acsv","Bcsv"]; //get csv files as a list 

 var file = fileArray.length; // add the list into an array

 var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(file.getBlob().getDataAsString()); // parse csv data


 if(numSheets==csvData){  // if array Index No of numSheets equals to index of file array

    numSheets.push(csvData);// push csv data into the sheet


    numSheets.clearContents(); //clear current contents in the sheet
    numSheets.getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData); // set values to the sheet
      }

   }

 })
}
```

The code does not show any errors but neither any data input to sheet from csv file. Can anyone explain why this happens like this please?

Comment: Hi, firstly in your forEach function you’re overwriting the value assigned to sheetArray at each loop instead of appending it to an existing array (e.g. using Array.push(s)). As it is now you’re just getting the last one, which is Sheet3. And...why are you calling a function with square brackets? DriveApp.getFilesByName() - with round brackets - gets a collection of files giving one file name. And again, Array.length returns the number of elements in the array. I suggest you to read something about JS, the docs at developers.google.com, and consider to use Logger.log() to debug your variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line is using the wrong syntax of `getFilesByName`:

```
var fileArray = DriveApp.getFilesByName["Acsv","Bcsv"]; //get csv files as a list
```

The correct syntax is:

```
DriveApp.getFilesByName(name);
```

Where name is a string. You should change your code accordingly.

On the other hand

```
var numSheets = sheetArray.length; // save sheets in Array
```

and

```
var file = fileArray.length; // add the list into an array
```

Assigns an integer to `numSheets` and `file` respectively, so the next code lines don't do what you expect, like

```
numSheets.push(csvData);// push csv data into the sheet
```

and

```
var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(file.getBlob().getDataAsString()); // parse csv data
```

Consider to spare some time to learn how the Google Apps Script debugger works so you can use it to efficiently debug your code.

Reference

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getfilesbynamename